# How to create a shapefile for 2 million points with GeoTools

Tags: shapefile, geotools

I have to create a shapefile with the GeoTools Java library for approximately  2000000 points and whatever strategy I apply I seem to run into "out of memory" exceptions as well as everything running super slow. Has anyone done successfully done this before?

Comment: Have you tried increasing your java heap size with a "java -Xms1g -Xmx1g" ?

Comment: you are unlikely to be able to use a shapefile with 2M points, even if you can overcome the size constraints in shapefiles (<2Gb IIRC) - consider using a database to store your data.

Comment: thanx iant, didn't know about this constraint. With a strategy of gnerating multiple small files and merging them together into one I hit the 2GB size limit at around 600 000 points...so I have to check with my customer if it makes any sense to continue

Comment: see http://support.esri.com/es/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/37447 for more details on size limits

Comment: Your question looks related to [this post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19815/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-create-a-shapefile-from-resultset-using-geotoo).
Try the answer I made there. 
(Gah, SE converted my answer to a comment...)